# Moving a large SQL query to Excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

Part of my current project involves populating an Excel worksheet from a large SQL table, which contains 120,000+ records.  I'm currently using SqlDataReader with a while loop to directly populate a new Excel sheet, but obviously this takes an unrealistic amount of time.  Building a local .CSV file with StringBuilder *then* opening that in Excel seems to be a faster option.  Is it preferred to dump the data to file every thousand rows or so, or write it all at once?  Or is there a more efficient way to import this data that I'm not considering?

The dataset is different depending on user input, so I can't simply append to an existing file.

Current code:

```
SqlConnection cnnct = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Integrated Security=True;");
            cnnct.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cnnct;
            string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
            cmd.CommandText = cmdText;

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                columnChar = 'A';
                rowCount++;

                cellName = columnChar.ToString() + rowCount.ToString();
                    ws.get_Range(cellName, cellName).Value2 = dr["EXAMPLE_FIELD"].ToString();
                    columnChar++;
                //The above three lines are identical for each field (there are 26)
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have performance tests to try the various options?  The code you have shown has nothing do with writing a CSV file.

Comment: As I said in the initial post, I'm currently using SqlDataReader with a while loop to directly populate a new Excel sheet.  I've been exploring different options, but I'm looking for an outside opinion before I go with building a CSV instead.  I'm not looking for code examples, I'm just curious if there may be a more efficient alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would avoid Excel interop at all costs.  Your idea of just writing a .CSV file has lots of merit.  As always with "best" performance it depends on environment, but unit tests always help.

`System.IO` is pretty optimal.  I would just read a row from `SqlDataReader` and write the CSV line.  It becomes very simple code and I bet is fairly "fast".

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One big problem is that you're populating the Excel sheet cell-by-cell, which is slow because you're making a COM-interop call every time you call the `.Value2` setter.

It would be MUCH faster if you allocated an array for ALL of the data you intend to put in excel (M rows by N columns), created a range object to represent that range, and copied the array to the range using the `.Value2` setter.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet` in c#, you can write that dataset to `Xlsx` format or create xml file `using System.xml` or use thrid party tool/create own excel xml, to create xls format.